# Saving a series of manually selected points

Tags: matlab

Just a quick question. I have generated a piece of code whereby I select the point of interest in every frame. However, the coordinates of the last selected point is the only one that is saved. Does anyone know how to set up the code such that all the points for each frame are saved for example in a text file with x position in column 1 and y position in column 2? Here is the code I have developed so far;

```
clear;
clc;

%% Video file information
obj = VideoReader('T9_720p_60p_60mm_f5.MOV');

%% Sampling rate 
fps = get(obj, 'FrameRate');
dt = 1/fps;

%% Image Information
file_info = get(obj);
image_width = file_info.Width;
image_height = file_info.Height;

%%Desired image size
x_range = 1:image_height;
y_range = 1:image_width;
szx = length(x_range);
szy = length(y_range);

%%Image processing - Point selection
for n = 33:115
    frame = read(obj,n);
    imshow(frame);
    hpoint = impoint(gca, []);
    Position = getPosition(hpoint);
end
```

Comment: You can set global variable or use handle and append new coordinates to older ones.

Answer (score 1):

I  just realized all I need was to add the following before the end of the loop

```
%%Save data

n = n-32;
data(n,:) = [Position];
end
```

Regards

Comment: For speeding up the code you should preallocate `data=nan(115-32,2);` before the `for` loop.